# Can you sort by subclass?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to list through subclass value? I'd like 'by' variable to be the first one and sort entire list by .number subclass.

```
class Abcd:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number

ax = Abcd("a", 20)
by = Abcd("b", 1)

lst = [ax, by]

print lst[0]
list.sort(lst)
print lst[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do. All I am doing is adding a key to the sort function and some stuff to make printing look better but those really aren't necessary.

```
class Abcd:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} and {}".format(self.name, self.number)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

ax = Abcd("a", 20)
by = Abcd("b", 1)

lst = [ax, by]

print str(lst)
list.sort(lst, key=lambda x: x.number)
print str(lst)
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for help